# How can I access the comment columns when using CNTKTextFormat reader?

Tags: cntk

I can't figure out how to access the comment columns in my data files that are in CNTKTextFormat.  For example, in this [tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Tutorials/CNTK_202_Language_Understanding.ipynb), you have the following:

```
19  |S0 178:1 |# BOS      |S1 14:1 |# flight  |S2 128:1 |# O
19  |S0 770:1 |# show                         |S2 128:1 |# O
19  |S0 429:1 |# flights                      |S2 128:1 |# O
```

How can I access the commented data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you instantiate your minibatch source like this:

```
data_source = (CTFDeserializer("mydata.ctf", ...), randomize=False, ...)
```

you can then open the input file you passed to CTFDeserializer with Python and parse it minibatch by minibatch. It is **very important** to set `randomize=False` otherwise the reader and your manual parsing below will not be in sync. For example if the file object is `stream` and the minibatch size is `batch_size` the following code will print each sequence's commented columns as a dictionary mapping the preceding column name (S0, S1, or S0) to the sequence of strings found in the comment columns.

from itertools import groupby
     from collections import defaultdict

```
 stream = open("mydata.ctf")

 lines = [stream.readline() for i in range(batch_size)]
 for seqid, sequence in groupby(lines, lambda s:s.split()[0]):
     mapping = defaultdict(list)
     for sample in sequence:
         parts = sample.split('|')
         unused = [mapping[parts[i-1].split(' ')[0].strip()].append(p.strip()) for i, p in enumerate(parts) if p.startswith('#')]
     print(seqid, mapping)
```

For the above example input it produces:

```
19 defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'S0': ['# BOS', '# show', '# flights'], 'S2': ['# O', '# O', '# O'], 'S1': ['# flight']})
```

This example will work for the above input format. If your actual format is different you will have to adapt this for your purposes.